# History of commands and directories we were in

Tags: bash, command-history

I was wondering: If I type `history` I can see the previous commands I typed and see what happened and perhaps keep commands as reference. But I don't know in which directory I was when I typed the commands.

Is there a version of `history` that displays also the directory you were in when you typed the command?

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/945288/2100043

Comment: [Per-directory history in zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71189/per-directory-history-in-zsh) may be interesting, if you're ok with switching to zsh.

Comment: @Gilles:I have never used `zsh`.Is it separate download?Does it work ok with `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: @Jim It's a separate program. Most distributions offer it as a package. Zsh is less common, often not part of the default installation, but has more features. The basic syntax is mostly the same, but some advanced features are different, and zsh has [more](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/983). The two work equally well in screen or tmux.

Answer (score 2):

Following the link about *Per-directory history in zsh* and then the link in the comment there, two Per-directory history in bash links are provided (one is broken, but corrected here):

- [BASH: Per directory BASH history](http://www.compbiome.com/2010/07/bash-per-directory-bash-history.html) - on compBiomeBlog
- [Per-directory bash history](http://dieter.plaetinck.be/per_directory_bash_history.html) - Dieter on the web