# what does extended_history in zsh do?

Tags: zsh, command-history

I saw the option extended_history and saw it being used as in [Per-directory history in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71189/per-directory-history-in-zsh) but haven't really understood what does extended_history actually do ?

What info. would become available in zsh_history which otherwise wouldn't if this option is not set.

From http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Options it says about -

```
EXTENDED_HISTORY <C>

    Save each command’s beginning timestamp (in seconds since the epoch) and the duration (in seconds) to the history file. The format of this prefixed data is:

    ‘: <beginning time>:<elapsed seconds>;<command>’.
```

But I don't see any benefit to it at least while running the history command -

```
 shirish@debian ~ % history | grep tail -5
      601* exit
      602* history
      603* exit
      604  cd
      605  cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc
      606   tail -5 history
```

This is how my `~/.zsh/.zshrc` is set up -

```
shirish@debian ~ % cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.zsh//.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=100000
setopt inc_append_history autocd nomatch notify share_history extended_history
bindkey -e
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install

# display how long all tasks over 10 seconds take
export REPORTTIME=10

# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/shirish/.zsh//.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit promptinit
compinit
promptinit
# End of lines added by compinstall

prompt adam1
```

I didn't see any difference either after setting the option or taking it out, no meaningful difference.

```
shirish@debian ~ % cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc | grep setopt
setopt inc_append_history autocd nomatch notify share_history extended_history
shirish@debian ~ % source ~/.zsh/.zshrc           
shirish@debian ~ % history -E                     
  337  11.1.2018 23:33  history | grep apg
  338  11.1.2018 23:33  man apg
  339  11.1.2018 23:33  cd
  340  11.1.2018 23:33  apg -a 1 -M n -n 3 -m 20
  341  11.1.2018 23:33  apg -a 1 -M SNCL -n 3 -m 20
  342  11.1.2018 23:33  history 
  343  11.1.2018 23:33  history -E
  344  11.1.2018 23:33  leafpad ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  345  11.1.2018 23:33  cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  346  11.1.2018 23:33  source ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  347  11.1.2018 23:33  history -E
  348  11.1.2018 23:33  exit
  349  11.1.2018 23:33  history -E
  350  11.1.2018 23:34  leafpad ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  351  11.1.2018 23:35  cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc | grep setopt
  352  11.1.2018 23:35  source ~/.zsh/.zshrc
shirish@debian ~ % leafpad ~/.zsh/.zshrc          
shirish@debian ~ % source ~/.zsh/.zshrc 
shirish@debian ~ % history -E           
  340  11.1.2018 23:33  apg -a 1 -M n -n 3 -m 20
  341  11.1.2018 23:33  apg -a 1 -M SNCL -n 3 -m 20
  342  11.1.2018 23:33  history 
  343  11.1.2018 23:33  history -E
  344  11.1.2018 23:33  leafpad ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  345  11.1.2018 23:33  cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  346  11.1.2018 23:33  source ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  347  11.1.2018 23:33  history -E
  348  11.1.2018 23:33  exit
  349  11.1.2018 23:33  history -E
  350  11.1.2018 23:34  leafpad ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  351  11.1.2018 23:35  cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc | grep setopt
  352  11.1.2018 23:35  source ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  353  11.1.2018 23:35  history -E
  354  11.1.2018 23:36  leafpad ~/.zsh/.zshrc
  355  11.1.2018 23:36  source ~/.zsh/.zshrc
shirish@debian ~ % cat ~/.zsh/.zshrc | grep setopt
setopt inc_append_history autocd nomatch notify share_history
```

As can be seen there doesn't seem to be any difference.

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: FYI http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fHISTORY

Comment: @counglm, I added a bit more info. so now it might make it easier to understand why it doesn't seem to help in anyway.

Comment: what happens if you put `-E` on the `history` command to show the timestamps when `EXTENDED_HISTORY` is on or off between different invocations of the shell?

Comment: I don't see a difference in either way.  I'll add it to the question as well.

Comment: @shirish Can you start a clean shell session and retry?

Comment: By clean shell session, do you mean by removing ~/,zsh/.zshrc , Rebooting the system and then trying the command you shared then yes would be able to do it in few hrs.

Answer (score 6):

The output of `history -E` will always be the same regardless of the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` option. The duration of the command is stored directly in the history file (just examine the file to see the values).

However, another gotcha is that there are a few options that will override this behavior. You can test to see if it is working by running a command like `sleep 3`, which should result in an entry that looks like this:

```
pol@host ~ $ sleep 3
pol@host ~ $ tail -1 ${HISTFILE}
: 1530663493:3;sleep 3
pol@host ~ $ setopt | grep hist
extendedhistory
histignoredups
incappendhistorytime
```

You can see that the "duration" value is 3. If it is not 3, then it is likely that you have another option set that is preventing `EXTENDED_HISTORY` from working.  These include `SHARED_HISTORY` and `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`. If you need the former, then you are out of luck.  For the latter one, there is an alternative `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME` that you can use instead if you want to also have `EXTENDED_HISTORY` values (as I have above).

Answer (score 3):

I will note that answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453336/277040 is slightly misleading. Indeed, the output **format** of `history -E` will be the same regardless of the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` status, but the timestamps will be relatively meaningless if `unsetopt EXTENDED_HISTORY` was always the case for your Zsh sessions. Each line of the `HISTFILE` will contain a command without any timestamp info, so `history -E` outputs the same time for all of these commands (the time that particular shell was opened and the `HISTFILE` was read into it's memory).

For example, given `~/.zsh_history` containing commands executed at different hours in the past:

```
echo 1
echo 3
echo 5
```

When I open a shell at 5:03 pm on the day I wrote this answer, `history -E` outputs:

```
    1  24.6.2020 17:03  echo 1
    2  24.6.2020 17:03  echo 3
    3  24.6.2020 17:03  echo 5
```